# uitableviewcell with uitextview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview, autoresize

I have an editable textview inside a tableviewcell, like the field notes in apple contacts, but the tableviewcell doesn't resize with the textview. I think that the problem is in this method. Can anybody help me?

```
 - (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) 
    {
        if (self.textView.contentSize.height >= 44) 
         {
            float height = [self heightForTextView:self.textView containingString:self.model];
            return height + 8; // a little extra padding is needed
         }
        else
         {
            return self.tableView.rowHeight;
         }

    }
    else 
    {
        return self.tableView.rowHeight;
    }
}
```

Comment: your textview has static height or dynamic? and are you trying to store the height in the height variable?

Comment: you need to, reload row again. 
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

this will recreate your textfield again. So keep your text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best example for the editable Cell as per your requirement. UITableViewCell that automatically adjusts its height as you enter text and you can managed it easily.

[AutoResizingEditableTableViewCell](https://github.com/jacquesf/AutoResizingEditableTableViewCell)